# Javascript/jQuery: populate a select with options taken from another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, select

I have these 2 `<select>`s:

```
<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
</select>
```

I need a javascript/jquery script that when I select an option from select 1 it populates the second select with the options next to the one it was selected.

**Example**: I choose 10AM from select 1 and the scenario should become:

```
<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>
```

I tried with this script but doesn't work:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.js-select-1', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var optionSelectedIndex = $(".js-select-1").prop('selectedIndex');

  var options = $('.js-select-1').find("option");

  //var optionsArr = options.slice();
  var optionsArr = $.extend(true, [], options);

  optionsArr.slice(0, optionSelectedIndex + 1).remove();

  $('.js-select-2').html(optionsArr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
</select>
```

It removes all the options from select 1 and populates the select 2 with all the initial options of select 1.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Agreed with @Barmar - what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: @KevinFriedheim I added the javascript I'm working on in the first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter version, using jQuery [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector and [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):

```js
$('select.js-select-1').change(function(e) {
  var $options = $(`option:gt(${this.selectedIndex})`, this).clone();

  $options.appendTo(
    $('select.js-select-2')
      .find('> option:not(:first)')
      .remove()
      .end()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
</select>
```

The reason we need to [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the filtered `<option>`s is that without this, those elements will be detached and appended onto the target element instead of actually copied over.

Comment: Updated to have the first `option` in the second `select` preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You're moving the elements from one `<select>` to the other. If you want to leave them in the original menu, you need to clone them.

There's no need for the array, you can just iterate over the jQuery collection.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.js-select-1', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var optionSelectedIndex = $(".js-select-1").prop('selectedIndex');

  var options = $('.js-select-1 option:gt(' + optionSelectedIndex + ')');
  $(".js-select-2").empty();
  options.each(function() {
    $(".js-select-2").append($(this).clone());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12AM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Awesome. Why not to clone the whole `options` variable (instead of cloning inside the loop) and then inject with `.html()`? Like the @jom's solution

Comment: I originally coded by answer using `.html()` rather than `.clone()`, but that didn't work. I changed it to `.clone()` and didn't realize I no longer needed the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that is a little more flexible.

```js
$('select.js-select-1').change(function(e) {
  var i = $("option:selected", this).index();
  var opts = $("option:gt(" + i + ")", this).clone();
  $('.js-select-2 option:gt(0)').remove();
  $('.js-select-2').append(opts);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-select-1">
  <option disabled>Start date</option>
  <option>08AM</option>
  <option>09AM</option>
  <option>10AM</option>
  <option>11AM</option>
  <option>12PM</option>
  <option>01PM</option>
  <option>02PM</option>
  <option>03PM</option>
  <option>04PM</option>
  <option>05PM</option>
</select>

<select class="js-select-2">
  <option disabled>End date</option>
</select>
```

Anytime you change the Start Date, it will update the End Date.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In what your solution is better than the @jom's one?

Comment: @FredK largely the same. Just does not remove the first `<option>` element.

Comment: @FredK I updated mine to have the first `option` in the second `select` preserved, in case you need it.